# How can repeatedly subtract the rows of a data matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 1000×2 matrix as follows:

```
         A B
Row1     0 2
Row2     0 3
Row3     0 4
Row4     0 5
Row5     0 3
Row6     0 4
         ...
         ...
Row999   0 8
Row1000  0 9
```

I want to add a new column C to the matrix. The elements of the new column C are obtained by calculating the ratios of the sum of consecutive blocks of Column B. Each block contains two elements. In other words, I want to get the following matrix:

```
         A B   C
Row1     0 2  2/(2+3)
Row2     0 3  3/(2+3)
Row3     0 4  4/(4+5)
Row4     0 5  5/(4+5)
Row5     0 3  3/(3+4)
Row6     0 4  4/(3+4)
         ...
         ...
Row999   0 8  8/(8+9)
Row1000  0 9  9/(8+9)
```

I don't know how to do this in R. Could anyone help me with this? Thank you very much. (Sorry for my poor English expression, I am not a native speaker.)

Comment: your problem is not particularly well defined. I don't think adjacent is the right term for this, since otherwise row2 is adjacent to both row 1 and row3, but that doesn't match what you are doing. You should also specify what to do for edge cases (first/last). Finally...at least try it yourself before asking for specific help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to wanna sum consecutive blocks of two elements, and you can do, if `m` is your matrix:

```
library(zoo)

cbind(m, m[,2]/rep(rollapply(m[,2], 2, sum, by=2), each=2))
```

Or base `R`:

```
x = m[,2][!!seq(nrow(m))%% 2] + m[,2][!seq(nrow(m))%% 2]
cbind(m, rep(x, each=2))
```

Comment: Thank you, Colonel Beauvel, your second method is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Another base attempt using `prop.table` to do the calculations within each group, via `ave`:

```
ave(dat$B, cumsum(seq(nrow(dat)) %% 2), FUN=prop.table)
#[1] 0.4000000 0.6000000 0.4444444 0.5555556 0.4285714 0.5714286
#### 2/(2+3)   3/(2+3)   4/(4+5)   5/(4+5)   3/(3+4)   4/(3+4)
```

Or even just:

```
dat$B / ave(dat$B, cumsum(seq(nrow(dat)) %% 2), FUN=sum)
```