# R: calculating fraction of values in column, grouped by value in another column

Tags: r

I have tried to find a solution to this for hours. I have tried to search SO, and should I have overlooked an answer for this, please close this as duplicate.

I have a matrix, sorted by `transcript_id`, then `cond`:

```
transcript_id    cond    expr
A1               B1      40
A1               B2      30
A1               B3      20
A2               B2      35
A2               B3      45
A3               B1      23
A4               B1      64
A4               B3      43
```

I would like a new column, where the fraction of `expr` within each `transcript_id` is listed:

```
transcript_id    cond    expr   frac
A1               B1      40     0.4444
A1               B2      30     0.3333
A1               B3      20     0.2222
A2               B2      35     0.4375
A2               B3      45     0.5625
A3               B1      23     1
A4               B1      64     0.5981
A4               B3      43     0.4019
```

Is there a smart way to achieve this?

My naive approach would be to write a function that loops over every unique element in `transcript_id`, but I am stuck.
Note that not every `transcript_id` is represented by all three `cond`.

Comment: Very similar to this one from the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335398/how-can-repeatedly-subtract-the-rows-of-a-data-matrix-in-r/3333629 - use `ave` to make the calculations in each group: `with(dat, ave(expr, transcript_id, FUN=prop.table) )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
#setDT converts to a data.table and then you calculate the fraction of each expr
#grouping by the transcript_id
setDT(df)[, frac := expr / sum(expr), by=transcript_id]
```

Output:

```
> df
   transcript_id cond expr      frac
1:            A1   B1   40 0.4444444
2:            A1   B2   30 0.3333333
3:            A1   B3   20 0.2222222
4:            A2   B2   35 0.4375000
5:            A2   B3   45 0.5625000
6:            A3   B1   23 1.0000000
7:            A4   B1   64 0.5981308
8:            A4   B3   43 0.4018692
```

Comment: Np, glad I could be of help. It is worth your time I guarantee you that. It is extremely fast if you have a big table too.

Answer (score 4):

For Solving the you'r problem Consider

1.group the your transcript_id column

2.Create the your required column using the two ways ***dplyr*** or ***plyr*** packages , i wrote the two ways .

```
using ***dplyr***.  

dataset %>% 
          dplyr::group_by (transcript_id) %>% 
             dplyr::mutate(frac=round(expr/sum(expr),4))




using ***plyr***.

plyr::ddply(dataset,.(transcript_id),plyr::summarise,frac = 
                                                 round(expr/sum(expr),4))
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, it makes it easier for people to understand.